# Как в тесте сделать задержку чтобы страница полностью загрузилась?

Tags: java, junit

Как использовать метод waitUntil чежду двумя кликами на checkbox, чтобы страница при клике на первый checkbox успела загрузиться?
Вот код метода:

```
@Test
public void produrtTest(){
    onSite().onMainPage().getButton().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"-category-section\"]/div/ul/li[1]/label/span")).click();
    onSite().onMainPage().getButton().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"-category-section\"]/div/ul/li[2]/label/span")).click();

}
```

Comment: Какая страница? О каком фреймворке речь?

Comment: А пример как в [документации](https://github.com/qameta/atlas#working-with-elements) не работает? Если не работает, то напишите, что именно не так?

Comment: onSite().onMainPage().getButton().waitUntil(WebElement::isDisplayed).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"-category-section\"]/div/ul/li[1]/label/span")).click(); как то так?

Comment: аргументы waitUntil подчеркиваются красным

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью UiAutomator. В классе `UiDevice` есть метод `wait()`

```
/**
     * Waits for given the {@code condition} to be met.
     *
     * @param condition The {@link SearchCondition} to evaluate.
     * @param timeout Maximum amount of time to wait in milliseconds.
     * @return The final result returned by the {@code condition}, or null if the {@code condition}
     * was not met before the {@code timeout}.
     */
    public <R> R wait(SearchCondition<R> condition, long timeout) {
        return mWaitMixin.wait(condition, timeout);
    }
```

Comment: Дело в том что я использую io.qameta.atlas.core.Atlas; и здесь есть метод waitUntil, трудности в его адаптации к данному коду

Comment: Ну если вы используете его, то и работать надо с ним и адаптировать код под него. Возможно стоит поискать что-то подобное в Espresso, но я так сходу найти не смог